Azure Pipeline: Merge from fork's upstream source across projects
I have two projects in the same organization. Project B has a fork from Project A. I want to refresh Project B's fork's main branch with the latest from Project A in an Azure Dev Ops Pipeline.
I can do this all locally on my machine with the commands in the yaml below. I believe the only issue I am facing is a permissions issue. Here's my current yaml from the pipeline in Project B:
name: ProjectB.UniqueRepoName.fork - merge from upstream fork
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true
  fetchDepth: 0

- script: |
   git config --local user.email "REDACTED"
   git config --local user.name "REDACTED"
   git fetch --all
   git remote add upstream https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/ProjectA/_git/UniqueRepoName
   git remote -v
   git fetch upstream
   git checkout main
   git merge upstream/main -m "Merging from upstream into this fork's main via manual Azure Pipeline"
   git push origin
   git status

With this I am getting these results:
origin  https://ORGANIZATION@dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/ProjectB/_git/UniqueRepoName.fork (fetch)
origin  https://ORGANIZATION@dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/ProjectB/_git/UniqueRepoName.fork (push)
upstream    https://$env:***@dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/ProjectA/_git/UniqueRepoName (fetch)
upstream    https://$env:***@dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/ProjectA/_git/UniqueRepoName (push)
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/ProjectA/_git/UniqueRepoName/'
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
Switched to a new branch 'main'
merge: upstream/main - not something we can merge
Everything up-to-date
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Finishing: CmdLine

I have given the "Project B Build Service (ORGANIZATION)" user account Contribute, Contribute To pull requests, Create Tag, and Read permissions in Project A.
I have given the "Project B Team" group account Contribute, Contribute To pull requests, Create Tag, and Read permissions in Project A.
In the organization I have shut off the Pipelines -> Settings of "Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines", "Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines", and "Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines".
What am I missing? I have tried replacing "$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" with "$(SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)", but that gives me an error about interactivity with the local screen, so I don't think that's incorrect.
